# QT GraphicsView become black

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qgraphicsview

I have this simple Dialog in QT:
[image]

when I click on "opzioni" appears a new block of buttons..but the two white object (QGraphicsView) become black..
I can't make a screenshot because when I press a key or move it, it becomes white again XD

I tried overloading resizeEvent()

```
void Dialogo::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * e )
{
 if(immagine)
 immagine->update();
 if(mappa)
 mappa->update();

 QDialog::resizeEvent(e);
}
```

whith immagine and mappa my QGraphicsView
but nothing. Why this ?

In my Dialog constructor I have

```
   setupUi(this);
   layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

The final result when I press "opzioni" would be
[image]

Comment: Show please code of opzioni slot. How does it work?

Comment: It is done in QT Designer; It simply do this
QObject::connect(opzioni_tasto, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), file_groupbox, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
where file_groupbox is a groupbox of buttons and LineEdit; I add a screenshot of what happens when I click on "opzioni" (whithout black areas)